# libtool confused with libstdc++.la during cross-compilation

Tags: cross-compiling, autoconf, libtool

I'm working on building a C++ library, exposed through python, for an ARM processor (a Xilinx ARM7).  Another on my team has forged the way using yocto to make a compilation environment suitable for this platform.  I mention this only to point out that I'm not familiar, much at all, with cross compilation environments.  This is all quite new to me.

In preparation for this work, I have been converting the build process for this library from the home-baked system (we wrote our own `Makefile`s) to using *The GNU Build System*.  Specifically, I'm using autoconf, automake and libtool.  All works quite well in a "standard" environment (tested on CentOS 6 and CentOS 7 and Ubuntu), but I've run into problems with the cross compilation.

My configure command line at present:

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/src/afalanga/crisscross/tmp/sysroots/zc706-zynq7/usr/include/python2.7 LDFLAGS=-L/src/afalanga/crisscross/tmp/sysroots/zc706-zynq7/usr/lib LIBS=-lpython2.7 ./configure --build=x86_64-linux --host=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

I was happily compiling code until this error appears on stdout (?stderr?):

```
libtool: link: warning: '/src/afalanga/crisscross/tmp/sysroots/zc706-zynq7/usr/lib/libstdc++.la' seems to be moved
libtool: link: warning: '/src/afalanga/crisscross/tmp/sysroots/zc706-zynq7/usr/lib/libstdc++.la' seems to be moved
libtool: link: warning: '/src/afalanga/crisscross/tmp/sysroots/zc706-zynq7/usr/lib/libstdc++.la' seems to be moved
/bin/grep: /usr/lib/libstdc++.la: No such file or directory
/bin/sed: can't read /usr/lib/libstdc++.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/usr/lib/libstdc++.la' is not a valid libtool archive
```

As I understand how the cross-compilation environment is constructed, the file `libstdc++.la` should have the string `libdir=/usr/lib` because, when installed on the Xilinx board, it will be in /usr/lib.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

My question then is, why is this confusing *libtool*?  Also, why is libtool trying to go back to `/usr/lib/libstdc++.la`?  That file, truly, doesn't exist just as the libtool script thinks.  But it shouldn't be looking there anyway.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I know very little about libtool, but the lib**.la  file points to a static lib (lib**.a) that will be compiled into the binary. In other words it will reside within the binary on the target arm system rather then in /use/lib, so I'm assuming the /usr/lib path is for the host. It's .so libraries (shared objects) that are dynamically linked would potentially be placed in a path like /usr/lib

Comment: @daniellyons yes, this did get resolved.  I'm sorry that this question has lingered.  I cannot take credit however, I was pulled off to write a driver.  The problem ultimately boiled down to ill-constructed autotools macros which the other guy doctored to work.